# Is there a limit to the achievement progress by opening chests when trading in sets of Mysterious Conch?

Tags: genshin-impact

You can trade in three "Mysterious Conch," obtained by investigating set locations on the northern tidal flats and shore of Tatarasuna, at the little hut. So far, I have done this seven times, and each time the achievement tracker for opening chests in Inazuma progressed by one chest. Is there a limit to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I no longer gain achievement progress.

After receiving the grand prize, I no longer gain achievement progress, but I can still open one each day. I don't know whether this was due to a bugfix, or if there is a distinct quantity of chests that count towards progress.